# Nullify QString data bytes

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I use `QString`s to store passwords. If to be more precise, I use `QString`s to fetch passwords from GUI.
The point is that after password usage/appliance I need to nullify (zero) internal `QString`s data bytes with password to eliminate it from memory entirely.

Here are my investigations:

- After `QString` destruction it's data remains in memory nonzeroed;
- When I attempt to modify `QString` to fulfill it with zeroes it triggers copy-on-write idiom and allocates new memory for a modified variant of data. Old data remains untouched. Same happens even if I use `QString::data()` method. Not really sure why - probably because it returns not raw `char *` but `QChar *`;
- `QString::clear()`, `= ""` does actually the same COW as described above.

Q: How can I implement proper `QString` cleanup to prevent passwords leaks?

Comment: Yep, `data()` causes a deep copy to occur, so it wouldn't help.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#setRawData ?

Comment: I suppose the big hammer approach would be to replace the QString object with a char[128] array (or however long you think it ought to be); then you'd have direct access to the bytes and could be certain they'd get properly munged when you need to be.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner The problem is that password originally comes from GUI's `QString`. It means that even if I want to move it to char[128] afterwards, I need to make a `QString` cleanup somehow.

Comment: @arrowd Unfotinately, it does not work as well. Seems that it just become pointing to const `QChar *unicode` but old data is still in memory

Comment: How did you check that?

Comment: @arrowd Using Qt Creator memory viewer while debugging session.

Comment: Have you tried iterating through all the chars using QString's operator[] and zeroing them one by one? As per the docs, it returns modifiable reference to a char.

Comment: @NikolaiShalakin I see -- that's a tough problem to solve, since you don't know how many other QStrings the GUI code might have been keeping around either.  I wonder if you might have to write your own custom GUI element to be sure?

Comment: @KjMag So, as I said, when I try to modify `QString` it triggers copy-on-write. It does not matter how you do it: with `operator[]` or other modifying methods. It still the same. Due to Qt documentation: _Behind the scenes, QString uses implicit sharing (copy-on-write) to reduce memory usage and to avoid the needless copying of data._ It means that when I modify `QString` it cannot keep a shared state to an original source anymore and allocates new memory for modified string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've got two possible ways of bypassing copy-on-write. I've tried them and they seem to work - didn't use the Qt Creator's memory viewer, but the implicitly shared QStrings used in my code both pointed to the same zeroed data afterwards.

**Using constData()**

As written in the [Qt docs for QString::data() method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#data):

> For read-only access, constData() is faster because **it never causes a
>   deep copy to occur.**

So the possible solution looks like this:

```
QString str = "password";
QString str2 = str;
QChar* chars = const_cast<QChar*>(str.constData());
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    chars[i] = '0';
// str and str2 are now both zeroed
```

This is a legitimate use of `const_cast` since the underlying data is not really `const`, so no undefined behaviour here.

**Using iterators**

From the [Qt docs for implicit sharing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html):

> An implicitly shared class has control of its internal data. In any
>   member functions that modify its data, it automatically detaches
>   before modifying the data. **Notice, however, the special case with
>   container iterators; see Implicit sharing iterator problem.**

So let's move to the section describing [this iterator problem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#implicit-sharing-iterator-problem):

> Implicit sharing has another consequence on STL-style iterators: you
>   should avoid copying a container while iterators are active on that
>   container. **The iterators point to an internal structure, and if you
>   copy a container you should be very careful with your iterators. E.g.:**

```
QVector<int> a, b;
a.resize(100000); // make a big vector filled with 0.

QVector<int>::iterator i = a.begin();
// WRONG way of using the iterator i:
b = a;
/*
    Now we should be careful with iterator i since it will point to shared data
    If we do *i = 4 then we would change the shared instance (both vectors)
    The behavior differs from STL containers. Avoid doing such things in Qt.
*/

a[0] = 5;
/*
    Container a is now detached from the shared data,
    and even though i was an iterator from the container a, it now works as an iterator in b.
*/
```

It is my understanding that, based on the above docs fragment, you should be able to exploit this "wrong usage" of iterators to manipulate your original string with iterators as they don't trigger copy-on-write. It's important that you "intercept" the `begin()` and `end()` before any copying occurs:

```
QString str = "password";
QString::iterator itr = str.begin();
QString::iterator nd = str.end();
QString str2 = str;

while (itr != nd)
{
    *itr = '0';
    ++itr;
} // str and str2 still point to the same data and are both zeroed
```

Comment: Great to hear that. This was an interesting problem and I am just so glad that it has worked for you :)

Comment: Hi @KjMag Thanks for your answer. It gave me a reallly good hint. Anyway, in my test `str2` is not zeroed. I am using Qt5.7. Can you check it again? Which Qt version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You have to be aware of all the temporary copies that may be done. If you want to avoid this you must manually erase memory before deallocating each temporal copy. Unfortunately that cannot be done with the standard `QString` since the implementation is closed.

You can, however, specialise [`std::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) using a custom allocator, which, before deleting can clean up the memory block (see below for an example). You can use this new *secure string* to manipulate your password instead of a plain char array, if you find it more convenient. I'm not sure is `std::basic_string` can be specialised with `QChar`, but if not you can use any of the Unicode characters from C++11 (`char16_t`, `char32_t`...) instead if you need other than ANSI support.

Regarding the user interface, I think an option you have is to create your own text input widget, reimplementing the `keyPressEvent` / `keyReleaseEvent` to store the typed password into either the secure string or a char array. Also reimplement the `paintEvent` to display only stars, dots, or whatever other masking character you want. Once the password has been used just clear the array or empty the secure string.

---

**Update: example of secure string**

```
namespace secure {
  template<class T>
  class allocator : public std::allocator<T> {
  public:
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename std::allocator<T>::size_type size_type;

    template<class U>
    struct rebind {
      typedef allocator<U> other;
    };
    allocator() throw() :
      std::allocator<T>() {}
    allocator(const allocator& other) throw() :
      std::allocator<T>(other) {}
    template <class U>
    allocator(const allocator<U>& other) throw() :
      std::allocator<T>(other) {}

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type num) {
      memset(p, 0, num); // can be replaced by SecureZeroMemory(p, num) on Windows
      std::allocator<T>::deallocate(p, num);
    }
  };

  class string : public std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, allocator<char>> {
  public:
    string() :
      basic_string() {}

    string(const string& str) :
      basic_string(str.data(), str.length()) {}

    template<class _Elem, class _Traits, class _Ax>
    string(const std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Ax>& str) :
      basic_string(str.begin(), str.end()) {}

    string(const char* chars) :
      basic_string(chars) {}

    string(const char* chars, size_type sz) :
      basic_string(chars, sz) {}

    template<class _It>
    string(_It a, _It b) :
      basic_string(a, b) {}
  };
}
```